# Need an OrgChart using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

For all the charting requirements Highcharts has been truly awesome... 
Has anyone tried building organization chart. We need to build Org Chart.
I don't want to use some other library for Org Chart !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://github.com/skorunka/highcharts.tree
It is simple tree and customised for a specific purpose. Anyways, it can be easily extended to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Organization chart is not build-in, but you can use our API and use renderer to creat a chart.

Example:
- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer

Docs:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, Highcharts has an organization chart built-in: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/organization-chart